# How to resize div to a child image size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am making an image viewer in my website and currently stuck with one particular issue.

How can I resize parent div to a child image size? I made an example of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/hf0ca2z1/19/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.picture-viewer {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.picture-viewer-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.picture-viewer-frame img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.picture-viewer-frame-header {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-viewer">
  <div class="picture-viewer-frame">
    <!--Element to position to fit the child image size -->
    <img src="https://post.greatist.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/325466_1100-1100x628.jpg">
    <div class="picture-viewer-frame-header">
      Header Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is responsive to the screen size, so that it would look proper on any device /  screen and I want the image parent div element to resize to the size of the image. How can I achieve that?

I suppose I have to resize the div and then make an image the size of the div, but how do I resize the div to the image size? Also there could be any image with any kind of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Width and Height from parent Div and it will be fine.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.picture-viewer {
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60vh;
  z-index: 20;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.picture-viewer-frame {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.picture-viewer-frame img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.picture-viewer-frame-header {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-viewer">
  <div class="picture-viewer-frame">
    <!--Element to position to fit the child image size -->
    <img src="https://post.greatist.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/325466_1100-1100x628.jpg">
    <div class="picture-viewer-frame-header">
      Header Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to have the image not at 100% size but at let's say 85%? So that it wouldn't be so close to the screen edges. If I change max-width and max-height of the image the parent doesn't seem to adapt.

Comment: Also I just did some testing and it doesn't really work, cause when I change the height of the screen the image does not resize to adapt to the screen.

Comment: I have edited the answer check that. You can get apply height and width on upper div. The  "picture-viewer" div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to accomplish exactly.
Generally a div adjusts to the size of its contents.

To illustrate, if you change the background color of the immediate parent div, to say blue, you will see no change (nothing is blue) because the parent div adjusts to fit the image and is taken up completely by the picture.

So, do you mean the parent of the image, or the parent of that parent?

EDIT:
Have you tried padding around the image?

Comment: I want to resize the image parent to the size of the image. User 'Wajid' in the other answer stated that this can be fixed just by removing parent width and height from the CSS. And that did fixed the problem but I want the image to be not so close to the screen border, so not 100% but 85%, but if I change the image max-width and max-height to 85% the parent doesn't seem to adapt.

Comment: Yes I also tried adding padding, but it still creates same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use clientWidth or clientHeight to get your width and height of your div tag and have your specific ratio.
You can learn more in:
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_element_clientwidth.asp

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to have the parent be padded.
And use vw units for the sizes.
Here is an example:
(the image and the border resize as you resize the page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The img height attribute</h1>

<div style="padding: 20vw; background-color:blue;">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1855349/pexels-photo-1855349.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]